# Pandas: Access the level of MultiIndex for inplace operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with multiple attributes (shown here is only price) for commodities, indexed over tuples of (Location, Name, Type):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'price': {
 ('DE', 'Coal', 'Stock'): 2,
 ('DE', 'Gas', 'Stock'): 4,
 ('DE', 'Elec', 'Demand'): 1,
 ('FR', 'Gas', 'Stock'): 5,
 ('FR', 'Solar', 'SupIm'): 0,
 ('FR', 'Wind', 'SupIm'): 0}})
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index, names=['Sit', 'Com', 'Type'])
```

More readable:

```
                  price
Sit Com   Type
DE  Coal  Stock       2
    Elec  Demand      1
    Gas   Stock       4
FR  Gas   Stock       5
    Solar SupIm       0
    Wind  SupIm       0
```

**My question:** How can I concisely multiply the attribute `price` of all rows where `Type == "Stock"` is true?

I only found the following, involving temporarily reseting the index to access `Type` as a column. Is it possible to do the same more directly, by doing the comparison on the index directly?

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.loc[df['Type'] == 'Stock', 'price'] *= 2
df.set_index(['Sit', 'Com', 'Type'])
```

What I'd like to write - sort of:

```
df.loc[(:, :, 'Stock'), 'price'] *= 2
```

**Edit (Solution):** Thanks to [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu) for the boolean masking idea and to [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644898/jeff) for pointing out the lexsorted problem, which allowed me to fix my code, which finally looks like this:

```
df.sortlevel(0, inplace=True)  # ensures that df is lexsorted
mask = (df.index.get_level_values('Type') == 'Stock')
df.loc[mask, 'price'] *= 2
```

Comment: see here for new features in 0.14.0: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#multiindexing-using-slicers; the reason you sometimes get an error is that your index always must be lexsorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [23]: mask = (df.index.get_level_values(2) == 'Stock')

In [24]: df.loc[mask] *= 2

In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
                  price
Sit Com   Type         
DE  Coal  Stock       4
    Elec  Demand      1
    Gas   Stock       8
FR  Gas   Stock      10
    Solar SupIm       0
    Wind  SupIm       0
```

Comment: Thanks so far! I have one weird issue for transfering these lines to a multi-column frame: `df.loc[mask, 'price']` throws a `KeyError: 'Key length (2) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (0)'`. However, I fail to reproduce the error with the shown `df` and a randomly generated second column.

Comment: I just created a [pastebin with the exact frame I am using](http://pastebin.com/XXR028wy), but when I recreate the DataFrame from there, `df.loc[mask, 'price'] *= 2` works flawlessly. Digging deeper to reproduce...